# Cocos2d-x CCSprite->setDisplayFrame AccessViolation crash

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

So far I could track down every error/crash I had in my cocos2dx application, but now I feel myself dumb.
I have an array of CCSprite pointers, and what I want to do is to change it's display frame from the cache when the player has x score.

All the sprite frames are read from a plist file, and the sprite is there and working, because I can see it without any problem before trying to switch to the new frame. The "background.png" is a valid sprite frame name, since I'm using it to create the actual sprite which works.

This line works fine (or at least it seems to work)

```
CCSpriteFrame* frame = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName("background.png");
```

The problem is with this line:

```
for (int c = 0; c < sizeof(mBackground) / sizeof(CCSprite*); c++){
    mBackground[c]->setDisplayFrame(frame);
}
```

This one also crashes:

```
CCSpriteFrame* frame = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName("background.png");
mBackground[0]->setDisplayFrame(frame);
```

I ran out of ideas, I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Found the possible problem:
`CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName("background.png")`

Returns a null pointer. According to the documentation, it returns nil if the name is not found. The funny part is that I'm using the exact same name for creating the object.

Comment: If you create sprite with spriteWithFile constructor, it adds needed spriteframe to the cache if there is no such spriteframe there. If you try to get spriteframe from the cache, it will simply return null pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure image exists in cache.  If not exists then load spriteframe to cache first. Also add mBackground[0] to parent before changing display frame.

```
if(mBackground[0] && frame)
{
    mBackground[0]->setDisplayFrame(frame);
}
```